# JUnit timeout after running for 60 mins

Tags: junit, junit4

I have a test project for my actual code that resides in another project.
for example, if there is FunctionalModule that has all the code concerning the functionality, I have a test project FunctionalModuleTest.

My ant runs the tests from FuntionalModuleTest and code in the FuntionalModule project is tested.

There are many test cases and after 60 mins, the run halts with an error message -
"The following TestProjects were killed for running past the timeout (60mins).

Where is this configured? My ant and emma does not have the timeout configured. It is not in project properties. I want a way to override this config and keep the timeout unbounded.

Adding more information : Nov 22 2011

I am using ANT 1.7.0, Unbreakable linux [Linux ME 2.6.18-164.0.0.0.1.el5 #1 SMP Thu Sep 3 00:21:28 EDT 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux], Java with OracleDB

Comment: We need some more details in order to help you. Which version of Ant are you using, which task, your OS, java, etc. Otherwise we would be just guessing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the default 60 min timeout is set by ANT.
And to alter that, or to override that property, a command line property:

```
Dtest.lrg.timeout=240
```

(4 hrs) has to be added.

Comment: This property seems to come from your application and not from junit. The junit task has the timeout attribute, but no predefined property. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html

Answer (score 0):

What is causing your tests to take so long? You may want to break up your test suite into unit test (should be fast) and integration/system tests (can be slow). I would look at speeding up your tests before expanding the timeout.

This [Nabble Thread](http://old.nabble.com/JUnit-timeout-question-td23016176.html) seems to indicate it's your `TestRunner`, not Junit. If you want to set a global max for all tests, you can look at [The Timeout class in JUnit](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/Timeout.html) or [The elements for the Test Annotation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html)